# Cloudflare Worker template script error - country redirect

Tags: redirect, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I grabbed example script from the Cloudflare GitHub worker example page for a simple country redirect. It fails and I don't know why? (I am not particularly strong in code stuff).

Error is:

```
Script modified; context reset. worker.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'country')
    at redirect (worker.js:17)
    at worker.js:28 redirect @ worker.js:17 (anonymous) @ worker.js:28 Uncaught (in response) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'country')
```

The template code is:

```
/**
 * A map of the URLs to redirect to
 * @param {Object} countryMap
 */
const countryMap = {
  US: "https://example.com/us",
  EU: "https://eu.example.com/",
}

/**
 * Returns a redirect determined by the country code
 * @param {Request} request
 */
function redirect(request) {
  // Use the cf object to obtain the country of the request
  // more on the cf object: https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/request#incomingrequestcfproperties
  const country = request.cf.country

  if (country != null && country in countryMap) {
    const url = countryMap[country]
    return Response.redirect(url)
  } else {
    return fetch(request)
  }
}

addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  event.respondWith(redirect(event.request))
})
```

From

> https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflare-docs/blob/production/products/workers/src/content/examples/country-code-redirect.md

Does anyone have advice on this? This is being run on the Cloudflare Workers system.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem with the Worokers preview. `request.cf` is always `undefined` when using the embedded preview next to the editor. If you use `wrangler dev` to test your code instead, it will work correctly there, and it will also work once deployed.

Comment: I still have the same issue after publishing from Wrangler :(